# Are there Spirit Airlines kiosks at the airport on St Thomas, US Virgin Islands?

Tags: low-cost-carriers, spirit-airlines, us-virgin-islands, stt

Are there Spirit kiosks at the airport on St Thomas, USVI? I want to avoid the $10 fee and will not have a place to print my boarding pass on the island.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I flew out of there April 2018 and can confirm there were 3 kiosks in front of the Spirit Airlines check in desk.

Answer (score 3):

I've emailed the [Virgin Islands Port Authority](http://www.viport.com/about/departments.html) and received the following reply:

[image]

So the answer is **yes**, Spirit Airlines does have a kiosk at Cyril E. King airport on St. Thomas island.